# Are my odds higher predicting a $50/50$ bet with a constant or picking a random number each time?

Tags: probability

Consider a list of random binary digits (each being either $0$ or $1$).

What's the probability of turning profit, if each correct prediction adds a fixed amount to your balance, while each incorrect one subtracts a fixed amount from your balance (negative amount of balance is allowed - we are looking for what is the probability of a positive balance within n predictions (considering the balance starts at 0 and the fixed amount added/subtracted is 1))(both of the fixed amounts added/subtracted are the same):

1. Picking either $0$ or $1$ all the time.
2. Picking another random number ($0$ or $1$) each time.

My context is this:

I initially had this theory in my head that placing random bets each time, rather than having a constant to compare with all the time - has sorta the properties of having a higher chance to match because of the possible cases where the random numbers I'm predicting stray from the constant.

Also I had concerns on the other hand that if Each time I predict random - since it's random on the both ends (and so it have more variable outcomes) - it may have less chance to match as well.

I have no background in probability (I have learned math I guess in middle and high school but I don't think it has stuck).

My question is simple if any of those above concerns hold any merit.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146047/discussion-on-question-by-fisocpp-are-my-odds-higher-predicting-a-50-50-bet-wi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted the other day, FISO?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh well I was recently watching like "The Kelly Criterion" and looking into "Bayes". But yeah I guess your answer is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a large extent, this depends on exactly what is meant by "a list of random binary digits". It's actually a rather subtle concept, and I'd refer anyone interested to the discussion in Seminumerical Algorithms, which is Volume 2 of Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming. At the risk of over-simplifying Knuth's discussion, I'll put forward the idea that a list of bits is random precisely when there is no betting strategy that is better (or worse) than any other betting strategy. So, in the long run, it doesn't matter whether you always bet on zero, or alternate betting on zero with betting on one, or bet according to your own list of random bits.

Comment: To be precise, isn't this an example of *independence* of the random digits in a list? Of course, "independence" is just putting a name on the concept that most people have of a list of digits being random, because while a list of digits each of which is $1$ if the first coin toss I make on May 18, 2023 is heads and $0$ if it is tails, then each digit is random but the entire sequence is either $1111\ldots$ or $0000\ldots$, which most people would say is not random at all.

Comment: @David, I'd agree that *independence* is just a name, and needs to be fleshed out to be useful as a definition of randomness.

Comment: In any case, technical language (which wouldn't help OP) aside, the answer above seems to me to be the canonical answer to this question.